Engine P0013 Light on Intermittently
My Buick Regal check engine light is on intermittently with a P0013 code, but engine runs fine with no problem.
I checked and found exhaust camshaft emissions sensor may be faulty.
buick regal 2.4 litre engine mileage 37,400.

Year, make, model, engine, mileage, maintenance performed?

Looks like for GM related vehicles that code is for the variable valve timing actuator/solenoid that will phase the camshaft forward or retard the camshaft to allow for variable air intake.
It will entirely depend on what type of vvt actuator it is. Is the actuator and the oil control valve a single unit or separate?
